# Re-opening closed dialog puts it in the start position after moving it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using multiple instances of the JQuery-UI dialog along with draggable and resizable.
Whenever I drag or resize one of the dialog boxes, the position and dimensions of the current box are saved to a database and then loaded the next time the page opens.

This is working well.

However, when I close a dialog box and re-open it using a button, jQuery sets the position of the box back to its original location in the center of the screen.
Furthermore, I use a show effect to slide the box off to the left on closing and in from the left on re-opening.

I found two ways to update its position when the slide in animation is done, however, it still slides into the center of the screen, and I have yet to find a way to get it to slide in towards the location it is supposed to have.

Here are the parts of the code that play a part in this:

```
    $('.box').dialog({
        closeOnEscape: false,
        hide: { effect: "drop", direction: 'left' },
        beforeClose: function (evt, ui){
            var $this = $(this);

            SavePos($this);  // saves the dimensions to db
        },
        dragStop: function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);

            SavePos($this);
        },
        resizeStop: function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);

            SavePos($this);
        },
        open: function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.dialog('option', { show: { effect: "drop", direction: 'left'} } );
            if (init)  // meaning only load this code when the page has finished initializing
            {
                // tried it both ways - set the position before and after the effect - no success
                UpdatePos($this.attr('id')); 
                // I tried this section with promise() and effect / complete - I found no difference
                $this.parent().promise().done(function() {
                    UpdatePos($this.attr('id')); 
                });
            }
        }
    });

function UpdatePos(key)
{
    // boxpos is an object holding the position for each box by the box's id
    var $this = $('#' + key);
    //console.log('updating pos for box ' + boxid);
    if ($this && $this.hasClass('ui-dialog-content'))
    {
        //console.log($this.dialog('widget').css('left'));
        $this.dialog('option', { width: boxpos[key].width, height: boxpos[key].height });
        $this.dialog('widget').css({ left: boxpos[key].left + 'px', top: boxpos[key].top + 'px' });
        //console.log('finished updating pos');
        //console.log($this.dialog('widget').css('left'));
    }
}
```

The button that re-opens the box has this code on it to make that happen:

```
var $box = $('#boxid');
if ($box)
{
    if ($box.dialog('isOpen'))
    {
        $box.dialog('moveToTop');
    }
    else
    {
        $box.dialog("open")
    }
}
```

I don't know what jQuery-UI does to the box as it hides it (other than display:none) or to make it slide in, so maybe there's something I'm missing here that might help...

Basically, I need JQuery to remember the box' position and put the box back into that location when it is re-opened.

It took me days to make it this far, but this is one obstacle I have yet to overcome.

Maybe there's a different way I can re-open the box?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Forgot - this issue ONLY happens when I use my UpdatePos function to set the location of a box (i.e. on page load). When I drag a box with my mouse, close it, and re-open it, everything works. So I'm guessing there's one more storage location for the box' position that I'm missing here...

EDIT2:

After more messing with it, my code for debugging now looks like this:

```
        open: function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
    console.log('box open');
    console.log($this.dialog('widget').position());  // { top=0, left=-78.5}
    console.log($this.dialog('widget').css('left'));
            $this.dialog('option', { show: { effect: "drop", direction: 'left'} } );
            if (init)
            {
                UpdatePos($this.attr('id')); 
                $this.parent().promise().done(function() {
    console.log($this.dialog('widget').position());  // { top=313, left=641.5}
    console.log($this.dialog('widget').css('left'));
                    UpdatePos($this.attr('id')); 
    console.log($this.dialog('widget').position());  // { top=121, left=107}
    console.log($this.dialog('widget').css('left'));
                });
            }
```

The results I'm getting are:

```
box open
Object { top=0, left=-78.5}
-78.5px
Object { top=313, left=641.5}
641.5px
Object { top=121, left=107}
107px
```

So looks to me as if the widget is being moved off screen (left=-78.5) and then moved for the animation, and then my code moves it into the location that it should be in (121/107).

The position() results for `$box.position()` or `$box.dialog().position()` do not change during this debugging section.

Maybe this will help someone here - I'm still out of ideas here...

... and I just discovered that when I drag the item around myself, then close and re-open it, it is very unpredictable. Sometimes, it will end up in the correct location horizontally, but not vertically. Sometimes, it will end up back in the center of the screen...

EDIT3:

So here's a jsfiddle version:

http://jsfiddle.net/semmelbroesel/KFqvt/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle demonstrating this issue?

Comment: A lot of the code is created from database data in PHP, so it'll take some work and simplifying, and I'm at the end of my work day, but I'll create something first thing in the morning.

Comment: Added jsfiddle (now it's working).

Comment: So you got it working now right?  I looked at your fiddle and could not find any issues with the modal boxes changing location after being closed..  http://jsfiddle.net/KFqvt/5/

Comment: Oh but your latest fiddle has some issues.. So something broke when you fixed the fiddle so that the modals would initialize on the page load with a different location/size.

Comment: I've been messing with it, sorry (I'll stop now)... The newest version does what it supposed to do - one box should originally start in a different position as loaded "via ajax" (in this case the variable boxpos is set manually instead of ajax). Now close the box that is NOT in the center, then use the button on the left to re-open it, and you'll see - I hope...

Comment: ... and now something else broke - gah... What is supposed to happen in the FINAL project: You close a box, push the button to re-open it, and it slides back into the position where it last used to be - not the center. What is supposed to happen in this demo (to show the functionality I have so far) is that you close and re-open the box, and it will slide into the center and THEN jump into its original position. What does happen right now is that it slides in the center and stays... But I'll stop messing with it for now so you can look at it.

Comment: Okay i'll look at it in a little while.  Need to finish up some other things first.

Comment: I am guessing the jquery saves the position of the box somewhere else other than in the element CSS of the ui-dialog element, but I haven't been able to find it yet, and I'm not quite sure how to read a jquery object - there's too many things to look through, and I can't find the useful information I need... On the other hand, the issue may also lie in `position` since the default is the center of the window, and I don't know how to override that without entering the coordinates - however, the array parameter is marked as deprecated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for anyone who had a look, but I found a workaround.

Instead of using the built-in `drop`, I decided to try doing that manually using `animate` where I have more control. So the relevant code now is this:

```
    $('.box').dialog({
        // REMOVED: hide: { effect: "drop", direction: 'left' },
        beforeClose: function (evt, ui){
            var $this = $(this);

            SavePos($this);

            $this.dialog('option', 'position', [ parseInt(boxpos[$this.attr('id')].left), parseInt(boxpos[$this.attr('id')].top) ]);

            $this.dialog('widget').animate({
                left: -$this.dialog('option', 'width') + 'px',
                opacity: 0
            }, 200, function(){
                // animation complete
            });
        },
        open: function()
        {
            var $this = $(this);
            // REMOVED: $this.dialog('option', { show: { effect: "drop", direction: 'left'} } );
            if (init)
            {
                UpdatePos($this.attr('id')); 
                $this.parent().promise().done(function() {
                    UpdatePos($this.attr('id')); 
                });
            }

            var thisLeft = $this.dialog('widget').css('left');
            $this.dialog('widget').css({
                'left': -$this.dialog('option', 'width') + 'px',
                'opacity': 0
            });
            $this.dialog('widget').animate({
                left: thisLeft,
                opacity: 1
            }, 200, function(){
                // animation complete
            });
        }
    });
```

Using that, I am now setting the start and end position for the slide in and the slide out effect, and it is working well now.

I'm still not sure what the original issue is, but it seems to have to do with `$box.dialog('option', 'position')`. I'll just jot down my findings here in case someone else finds them interesting.

By default, position is `{}`. If that is the case, jquery assumes the default of `{ my: "center", at: "center", of: window }`.

While the documentation claims that setting position to x/y coordinates using an array is deprecated, I noticed that when I drag the box around, `position` suddenly showed up as something like `[107, 250]`.

When I tried setting `position` manually before opening, my `console.log` entries showed that `position` is first set back to `{}` (which translates to "center of the screen"), then animates, then sets it back to the coordinates...

I don't know what is going on in the background here, and I'm very much aware how "abusive" my code is to the original thoughts behind `dialog` :-) So I figured I'd stop figuring out why my crazy idea of using this feature is not doing what I want it to do (and what it probably was never designed to do) and find another way to get the same effect - which worked.

Thanks again for looking!